# PostgreSQL connection issue - Dropping idle connections

Tags: postgresql, glassfish, database-connection, postgresql-8.4

**Brief Background:**

We have a cloud based Warehouse Management System that uses Glassfish to dish out the java interface. The Warehouse Management System consists of a Dashboard and a mobile application - both of which talk constantly with the Glassfish server (using a web browser).

**Issue:**

Recently our PostgreSQL database server HDD failed. After restoring from a backup and moving the database to an Amazon Web Service Server, idle connections seem to be dropping out. This causes the entire Warehouse Management System to fail. Restarting the Glassfish server seems to fix the issue until the idle connection causes it to fail again.

It happens around 3-4 times per day after approx 20mins of idle activity i.e. our customer's lunch breaks, after hours etc..

**Question:**

Is there a setting that I'm missing in the postgresql.conf file? What else could be causing this?

**Attachments:**

I've attached a screenshot containing the output of running 'select * from pg_stat_activity;' and also the postgresql.conf file.

[select * from pg_stat_activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSaDM.png)

[postgresql.conf](http://tinyurl.com/nkdod66)

**Log:**

postgresql-8.4-main.log shows this occasionally, although it doesn't seem to be when it cuts out.

```
2015-10-19 07:51:41 NZDT [9971-1] postgres@customerName LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

glassfish server.log is riddled with these lines:

```
[#|2015-10-19T07:46:49.715+1300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WebModule[/pns-CustomerName]Received InterruptedException on request thread

[#|2015-10-20T09:34:42.351+1300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8080(2).|

[#|2015-10-20T07:33:55.414+1300|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=14;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Response Error during finishResponse java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Glassfish has a couple of settings to check the DB connection. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4343/abehw/index.html